# XML creation from a Dictionary in Python

Tags: python, xml

I am quite new to XML as well as Python, so please overlook . I am trying to unpack a dictionary straight into XML format. My Code Fragment is as follows:

```
from xml.dom.minidom import Document
def make_xml(dictionary):
    doc = Document()
    result = doc.createElement('result')
    doc.appendChild(result)    

    for key in dictionary:
        attrib = doc.createElement(key)
        result.appendChild(attrib)
        value = doc.createTextNode(dictionary[key])
        attrib.appendChild(value)

    print doc
```

I expected an answer of the format

```
<xml>
 <result>
  <attrib#1>value#1</attrib#1>
   ...
```

However all I am getting is

```
<xml.dom.minidom.Document instance at 0x01BE6130>
```

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not checked the

http://docs.python.org/library/xml.dom.minidom.html

docs.

Look at the toxml() or prettyprettyxml() methods.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use a library like [xmler](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xmler) which easily takes a python dictionary and converts it to xml. Full disclosure, I created the package, but I feel like it will probably do what you need.

Also feel free to take a look at the source.